# Transgressions commute with the Steenrod operations on the base and fiber in a central group extension?

Tags: spectral-sequences, group-cohomology, at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, reference-request

The following sentence is quoted from the paper *ON THE COHOMOLOGY OF SPLIT EXTENSIONS* by D. J. BENSON AND M. FESHBACH:

**In general, the differentials in the Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence
for a group extension are difficult to understand. In the case of a central extension,
the $E_2$ page is easy to calculate and the transgressions may be computed
using the fact that they commute with the Steenrod operations on the base and
fiber.**

May I know what is the complete statement of the result "the transgressions commute with the Steenrod operations on the base and fiber" and which reference can I refer to for it? And why this makes calculation easy? Can anyone give some examples illustrating that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The statement in question refers to the Kudo-Serre transgression theorem: If $E_r$ is, for example, the LHS spectral sequence of a group extension and $x \in E_{2k+1}^{0,2k}$ is transgressive with $d_{2k+1}(x)=y$, then $$d_i(x^p)=0\;\;(i=2k+1,...,2kp)\quad \text{and }\;\; d_{2kp+1}(x^p)=P^ky$$ where $P^k$ denotes the Steenrod power operation  (a textbook reference is McCleary: A User's guide to spectral sequences, Theorem 6.14).

I'll give an example that is related to the Benson-Feshbach paper: Let $p$ be a prime and let $$1 \to C \to G \to Q \to 1$$ be a central extension with $C \cong (\mathbb{Z}/p)^n$ elementray abelian. If $k$ is a field of char. $p$ (with trivial $G$-action), than $Q$ acts trivially on $H^\ast(C;k)$ and by the universal coefficient theorem, the LHS spectral sequence satisfies 
$$E_2^{ij} \cong H^i(Q;k) \otimes_k H^j(C;k).$$
Moreover, $E_2 \cong H^\ast(Q;k) \otimes_k H^\ast(C;k)$ is an isomorphism of $k$-algebras (up to a sign). This is what is ment by B-F when they say the $E_2$-page is easy to compute.

The cohomology of $C$ is given by $H^\ast(C;k) = k[x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_n]$ with $\deg(x_i)=1, \deg(y_j)=2$ and the relations $x_i^2=y_i$ if $p=2$ and $x_i^2=0$ for $p$ odd. Note that $y_i = \beta(x_i)$ where $\beta$ is the Bockstein homomorphism.

In terms of the spectral sequence, we have $x_i \in E_2^{0,1}$. Hence $d_2(x_i) =: z_i \in E_2^{2,0}=H^2(Q;k)$, i.e. $x_i$ is transgressive. Now Kudo's theorem says that $d_2, \beta$ commute, i.e.
$$d_2(y_i) = d_2(\beta(x_i))=\beta(d_2(x_i))=\beta(z_i) \in H^3(Q;k).$$
Hence $y_i$ is again transgressive and by Kudo's theorem $d_5(y_i^2)=P^1\beta(z_i).$ Continuing this way, one obtains 
$$d_{2p^k+1}(y_i^{p^k})=P^{p^{k-1}}P^{p^{k-2}}\cdots P^1\beta(z_i).$$
As a result, the differentials on the fiber $E_\ast^{0,\ast}$ are completely determined by the values of $z_i \in H^2(Q;k)$ (the base) under the power operations.

Comment: Thank you @Ralph for your great answer!! Just to clarify a doubt:

In Theorem 6.14 of McCleary's book, the condition that the extension is central is not explicitly mentioned. In your example for the extension $1\to G\to Q\to1$ (I think you mean $1\to C\to G\to Q\to1$, right?), where did you actually use the "central" condition?

Comment: @Minghui: To say $Q$ acts trivially on the cohomology of $C$.

Comment: Also, in your example $k$ is assumed to be a field of char. $p$, while in Theorem 6.14, the coefficient field is required to be $\mathbb{F}_p$. Did you mean that Theorem 6.14 also holds for any field of char. $p$?

Comment: Thank you @Steve D! May I ask why the extension being central implies that $Q$ acts trivially on the cohomology of $C$?

Comment: Kudo's theorem holds in general (i.e. not only for central extensions and not only for the LHS spectral sequence). Centrality is used here to ensure that $x_i \in E_2^{0,1}=H^1(C;k)^Q$. Kudo's theorem is simplest to apply, if you can start with transgressive elements. 

Comment: Concerning $k$: We have isomorphisms $H^\ast(-;k) \cong H^\ast(-;\mathbb{F}_p) \otimes k$ (tensor product over $\mathbb{F}_p$). So Kudo also holds for general $k$. It's interesting to see that even May ("A general algebraic approach to Steenrod operations") uses mod-p cohomology while Steenrod in his original work just reguires the coefficients $A$ to satisfy $pA=0$. 

Comment: Concerning the triviality of the $Q$-action on $H^\ast(C;k)$: The action of $G$ (and hence the one of $Q$) on $H^\ast(C;k)$ is induced by the pair $(C \to gCg^{-1},\; k \to gk)$ (see Brown's book before Prop. 8.1). Since $C$ is central, the first is the identity and since $g$ acts trivial on $k$, the 2nd is also the identity. Hence the induced map is the identity as well. 

Comment: Thank you soooo much @Ralph!! Your answer definitely deserves to be the accepted one!

Comment: You are welcome. Also thanks to Steve for correcting the typo. 

Comment: @Ralph, great answer! I guess (since the Kudo theorem is stated for fibrations) you are implicitly assuming that the LHS spectral sequence of the extension coincides with the Leray-Serre spectral sequence of $K(G,1)\to K(Q,1)$? Is this true? If so, do you know of a reference (or is it essentially immediate from the constructions)? Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to use fibrations in  order use Kudo's t.t. for the LHS. Benson constructed Steenrod power operations entirely in terms of group cohomology using the bar resolution (cf. Representations and Cohomology II). But Kudo's t.t. is a general principal that holds in almost all spectral sequences that arise from filtered complexes over a category that admits power operations. This can be found in May's great paper "A general approach ..." cited in an earlier comment. 
